# can you have duplicate Call to Actions (CTA) on a Page?

Tags: gui-design, buttons, usability-testing, customer-experience, cta

What is the number of duplicate CTAs that we can have on the page? For example, "Request for a demo". Can this CTA appear more than once?

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Do you mean duplicate CTA?

Comment: Yes duplicate CTA.

Comment: I can think of a case where duplicate CTAs would be useful - in the case of a long scrolling page, you don't necessarily want users to scroll back to find a specific CTA, so having duplicates at relevant sections would be quite helpful for the users, especially if they are on a mobile device.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a [GoodUI](http://www.goodui.org/) design idea and A/B test report that indicates an **84% increase** in clicks due to repeated calls to action:

## [idea 5: Repeating Your Primary Action](http://www.goodui.org/#5)

[image: Repeating Your Primary Action]
The idea here is that a soft call at the top and prominent call at the bottom, after the user has reviewed the content, are helpful, but to balance the number of repeated calls with the length of the page to avoid annoying the user.

## [Test 46: More Calls To Action](http://www.goodui.org/evidence/test046)

**The Control:**
Converted at 7.0% with 40 of 573 visits

**The Variation with Repetition:**
Converted at 12.8% (**+84%**) with 108 of 843 visits

Albeit this is more of a test of *various* calls to actions, rather than directly testing a single repeated primary action.

Calls to action at the top:

- Locate a Distributor
- Download Product Catalogs
- Learn About Tube Fittings

Calls at bottom:

- Download Guide
- Access Catalogs
- Access Library

---

idea 5: http://www.goodui.org/#5
Test 46: http://www.goodui.org/evidence/test046

Answer (score 1):

For certain situations, a duplication of a CTA could be useful, but I would say this is very rare.

However, most of the time duplication would cause confusion and doubts, e.g. why are there 2 buttons with the same name? are they the same? or do they do something different?

These questions will form in the users mind and would cause someone to stop and think, which will interrupt whatever task they were performing.

So keep things simple - one clear call to action and no duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can have duplicate calls-to-action on a page! You just need to know how to balance it out. Typically I do this by having one at the top and one at the bottom - and sometimes slightly tweaking the language. It's also a good idea to do some A/B testing to track the success of your CTAs.

**Here's an article that has some examples of "balancing multiple CTAs on one page":** http://blog.hubspot.com/marketing/great-call-to-action-examples#sm.000149qz7t6x1f1ovlz1tx4ecztk3

[image: Here's an example from Uber]

Answer (score 0):

in case of websites it is good to have a duplicated CTA on the webpage.
but try to make it look different as in by changing color,position and text around that.

example:when your website needs user to sign-up,you ask it in different parts of the page..so user thinks that this CTA is important and user action is triggered.
but this works only in the cases of web pages.

Answer (score 0):

As people have mentioned above a CTA should be useful.  More importantly it should be relevant to the content.  Having more than one button saying 'Request a demo' would be fine, as long as it's in the right place.  For example at the top and then bottom of the page - it reinforces a message of what you want a user to do and they have a clear end goal.  It might become more appealing to appear next to another option so that it doesn't always look the same:

'find out more'  |  'request a demo'  |  'buy now'